# parse web service relational database

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using parse to develop an iOS app.
For the database, I have three tables, named `user`, `UserAndCourse`, and `course`.
Where `UserAndCar` stores a pointer to `user` and `course`.

the tables looks like:
[image]
[image]
[image]

My problem is:

How can I query the courses that belongs to the current user on iOS. i.e that look into UserAndCourse to find the rows that user column is current user and query for the course object that is pointed to by the course column.

Can I do this in a single relational query? or I have to query the UserAndCourse table rows first and then query the course it pointed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use PFRelation, that way you don't need to create new table for relations like userAndCourse. Parse automatically will link through the relation. You just need to create relation between them and do what you want.

Saving relation;

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
PFRelation *relation = [user relationForKey:@"course"];
[relation addObject:coursePFObject];
[user saveInBackground];
```

And query when you need to reach them;

```
PFRelation *relation = [user relationForKey:@"course"];
PFQuery *query = [relation query];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    // results contains all the people who subscribe to course
}];
```

Moreover you can specify your course by adding more queries on it;

```
PFQuery *query = [relation query];
[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:@"Math"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    // results contains all the people who subscribe Math course
}];
```

I think it's better way to shape your tables in parse. Otherwise you need to create table for each relation.

Hope it helps also if you need more detail [this](http://blog.parse.com/2012/05/17/new-many-to-many/) can be helpful.

Comment: I think the design concept of relational database does not suggest to do things like this. Will this effect my performance if there are too much data

Comment: I should had been mentioned its design pattern for one to many also if you want to add more parameters in your relations. You can create new table for relation.
But lets say you have database something like [this](http://web.mit.edu/11.521/www/lectures/lecture10/er_diag.jpg) you don't need to crate new table for it.